# IOS: check a part of a NSString

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I have this NSString:

```
NSString *test = @"three is a number";
```

I want to check if this NSString begin with "three"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the hasPrefix method:

```
if([test hasPrefix:@"three"])
{
  // Begins with three
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a more general approach, get a relevant substring, and compare it with the desired result.

```
if ([[test substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,5)] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"three"] == NSOrderedSame) {
     // ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's done by

```
if([test hasPrefix:@"three"]){
   ...
}
```

General answer: whenever you want to check if `NSString` (or any Apple-provided class,) look up the official documentation! In this case, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-hasPrefix_). You see, there's not only StackOverflow on the internet, there's the official documentation!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following:

```
if ([test hasPrefix:@"three"])
{
  // if YES
}
```